# How do I get the original i,j,k location in a blockwise operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

If I have an operation like `dask_array_object.blocks.ravel()` and iterate over the blocks resulting from that:

```
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>,
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>,
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>,
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>,
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>,
 dask.array<blocks, shape=(156, 156, 2126), dtype=float32, chunksize=(156, 156, 2126), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>...
```

how can I get the original i,j,k location of each part inside of the function that is executing in a blockwise fashion?

```
block_list = dask_array_object.blocks.ravel()

def store_data_into_binary(block_data, location_of_bin):
    # These are just functions that are specific to an internal library
    binary = open_binary(location_of_bin)
    block_data = block_data.compute()
    # How do I get these i, j, k locations?
    binary.put(block_data, (i0, j0, k0), (i1, j1, k1))
    # Attempt to remove the data from memory?
    block_data = None

for block in block_list:
    store_data_into_binary(block, "./location/of/file.bin")
```

Also, I noticed that there is an option of using the function dask.array.blockwise() for doing blockwise operations, same question. How can you know the original `i,j,k` location of the part in the dask array inside of the function executing in a blockwise fashion?

I tried using `map_blocks`, but since the function executed by `map_blocks` returns the block, I get my memory blown up.

Something like this:

```
import dask.array as da

x = da.random.randint(100, size=(2000,2000,2000)))

def func(x, block_id=None, block_info=None):
    # Grab the values of the 3D cube from Zarr disk store
    block_data = x.compute()
    # Function that writes the actual values to disk
    write_value_to_binary(block_data, "./file/datafile.bin")
    # Attempt to release the memory?
    x.close()

    return x

da.map_blocks(func, x).compute()
```

Is there a way to not have to return the actual numpy values and return something empty instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way may be to use `map_blocks` as you have, but just return the smallest array you can per function call

```
    return np.array([0])
```

However, the blocks outputted by `blocks.ravel()` are in exactly the order you would expect, and you can just follow its implementation:

```
for i, j, k in np.ndindex(x.shape):
    block = x.blocks[i, j, k]
    # do something with i, j, k, block
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would go through each i,j,k location in the `np.ndindex` right? When I loop through the indices wouldn't that add unnecessary steps? I would want to address the block instead of the particular i,j,k, but keeping track of where in the original cube that block is located.

You say that they are exactly in the order that you expect...I guess I don't understand exactly how `blocks.ravel()` works.

Comment: Yes, it loops through all the ijk. I don't know what it is to "address" the block and keep track of where it is located without the particular ijk. This is exactly what blocks.ravel() does internally.

Comment: I guess the question that is still in my mind boils down to: How do I reconstruct a 3D volume of "lego blocks" using the `.blocks.ravel()` function as if I were to grab each block and reconstruct it in another room by using the i,j,k positions of the original blocks. Block one would be from `0:50, 0:50, 0:35` (for example). I have a grid of the same size in a different room. How do you grab those original i,jk that correspond to the new location so I know where to place it? Using that dask function.

Comment: If you have the `i`th block along index 0, its first element in the `i` direction is i x the chunksize in that direction if you have even chunks, of the cumulative sum of chunk sizes up to the ith if not. Maybe update your question to specify what you need.